# JMSTranslationbundle The format "yml" does not exist

Tags: php, translation, symfony-3.4

I have used the JMSTranslationBundle before in different projects without any problem.

However this is my first Symfony3.4 project using the jms/translation-bundle: dev-master.

The configuration is as follows :

```
jms_translation:
configs:
    app:
        dirs: ["%kernel.root_dir%", "%kernel.root_dir%/../src"]
        output_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/translations"
        excluded_names: ["*TestCase.php", "*Test.php"]
        excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs, translations]
        output-format: yml
```

Running `php bin/console translation:extract --config=app en`
works fine and creates the right translation files. 
When I run the command again I get the following error :

```
The format "yml" does not exist.
```

Not to be mistaken with the ".yml~" doesn't exist error that I've seen on here before.

I have no problem when I use the xliff format, I can extract the files multiple times and it will work as it's supposed to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been going through all of the configuration files from previous projects for hours and I'm unable to pinpoint the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found away around this.

When I set the output format to 'yaml' instead of 'yml' there is no problem extracting the tranlsations multiple times. However the formatting is all messed up (no grouping).
This is not a great solution when the files start to become bigger.

So the problem does not come from the extraction of the translation nor the creation of the 'yml' files. It comes from when we try to parse the old files.

By adding the line

```
$format = ($format=='yml') ? 'yaml' : $format;
```

in the LoaderManager.php file from the JMSTranslationBundle at line 84 :

```
  protected function getLoader($format)
{
    $format = ($format=='yml') ? 'yaml' : $format;
    if (!isset($this->loaders[$format])) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The format "%s" does not exist.', $format));
    }

    return $this->loaders[$format];
}
```

Everything works as expected. The .yml file is generatedand formatted correctly. Any subsequent extractions keep the formatting intact without any errors.

Of course adding lines to a vendor bundle is not a real solution so I'll be looking into it more and submit a pull request when I've found an elegant way around this.